# How to use ng-disabled with jade templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, pug

Now I work with nodejs and investigate  angularjs for fun) But I have some problem I want to add file upload for my blog project and i did it) So I want show upload button only if user select some file. It is not a problem with jQuery but I want to know how to do it with angular. So here I have more problems

Here is Jade template

```
form(method="post",enctype="multipart/form-data", action="/imageUpload")
              label Select image 
              input(type='file',name='image',onchange="angular.element($(this)).scope().inputChange()")
              button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit,ng-disabled='{{isEnable}})#uploadBtn Upload Image
```

here is my work jQueryCod for validate

```
function UserController($scope)
{
    var sizeInput = $("input[type='file']").val().length;
    isEnable = sizeInput === 0 ;
    $( "#uploadBtn" ).toggle( isEnable )   
    $scope.inputChange = function(){
        sizeInput = $("input[type='file']").val().length;
        isEnable = !(sizeInput > 0);
        $( "#uploadBtn" ).toggle( isEnable );
    }
}
```

Of cource I can  use only jquery - but I want to know how angular works.

So I want to use ng-disbled - but it doesn't work correctly. At first load it takes position true - and it all - it doesn't change

```
function UserController($scope)
{       
    var sizeInput = $("input[type='file']").val().length;
    $scope.isEnable = sizeInput === 0 ;       
    $scope.inputChange = function(){
        sizeInput = $("input[type='file']").val().length;
        myScope.isEnable = !(sizeInput > 0);

    }
}
```

I have found answer that here we mast use not {{ isEnable}} but just ng-disabled='isEnable' without parentheses but how inject it to jade???

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `{{}}` since you're already writing in Angular inside `ng-*` attributes:

```
ng-disabled='{{isEnable}}
```

To:

```
ng-disabled='isEnable'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-show`

button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit,ng-show='isEnable')#uploadBtn Upload Image

This will tell angular to show your button only when `isEnable` is true. When it's false, the button won't be shown.

Comment: ng-show='isEnable' there is no difference with ng-disabled because it is jade template,Thx for attention.